# IPtables - new vs new, established, related

Tags: http, iptables

Let's take an example, let's assume that I would allow only outgoing HTTP[S] traffic to pass through the firewall. I know I would also need to allow outgoing DNS traffic in a real world scenario, but this is just an example. I would have written the iptable rules like this:

```
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP

-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Is this correct? I wonder because I have seen people who have written the same firewall rules like this:

```
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP

-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

What is the difference between `NEW` and `NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED` for an outgoing rule? Is it enough just to write `NEW` and let the firewall do some mysterious magic? Or is it necessary to write `NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED`?

Comment: As a note, the line is most commonly written this way: `-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`. This change essentially turns `iptables` into a stateful firewall. Instead of having to define each TCP connection properly, this line essentially allows all traffic that has already been processed (and allowed) by `iptables`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second configuration will not work (try it!).
Since your default policy is `DROP` on the `OUTPUT` chain, the third packet of the TCP three-way-handshake will be blocked by the firewall, as that one does not fall under `NEW`, so the connection will never be established.

It would work if your default `OUTPUT` policy would be `ACCEPT`, or you had some other `OUTPUT` rule afterwards which would allow `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED` state.

In conclusion, the first ruleset is the correct one, if you want to have `DROP` as your default policy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was what I thought, but i got a little bit confused when I saw someone write it with only `NEW`. I thought maybe IPtables creates some sort of records of established connection, and it was then unecessary to use `ESTABLISHED`.